# Как написать шейдер, делающий объекты слегка прозрачней?

Tags: unity3d, opengl, шейдеры

*Начинаю свой путь в техарте, более менее успешно был написан лишь простецкий blur shader.*

Сейчас передо мной стоит задача - написать шейдер, делающий объекты слегка прозрачней. Суть проблемы в том, что по сути это делается через транспарант, который устарел пару лет как (из документации Unity) - как работать с этой задачей через стандартный шейдер - я не знаю.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/224003/

Answer (score 0):

> это делается через транспарант, который устарел пару лет как (из документации Unity)

Не выдавай свои выдумки за документацию, такого там нет.

> **Из статьи [Legacy Shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/Manual/Built-inShaderGuide.html):**
>
> До введения стандартного шейдера на физической основе в Unity было более восьмидесяти встроенных шейдеров, каждый из которых служил для разных целей.

Ни о чем другом кроме **использования** стандартного шейдера, тут не говорится. К **написанию** шейдеров отношения вообще не имеет, от слова СОВСЕМ. Те кто знает, что такое `Draw Call`, понимают что это скорее всего была оптимизация по их уменьшению.

`через транспарант` что? [Transparent Shader Family](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-TransparentFamily.html) (из вышеупомянутой Legacy группы)? Так причем тут группа готовых шейдеров, если ты пишешь свой? Какое отношение он имеет к ним?

---

Нет никаких `через стандартный шейдер`. Есть только [Surface Shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html) и [Fragment Shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html).

```
SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
```

Вот что делает шейдер прозрачным!

---

П.C. [транспарант](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0) это растяжка с текстом!

Comment: Минус не мой, но я бы тоже поставил - это даже не ответ, а какие-то прям наезды на автора вопроса ..

Comment: @Kromster, он перепутал теплое с мягким, сказать что это все фигня не имеющая отношение к реальности и есть ответ.

Comment: Возможно ТС не прав в своих предположениях, тогда стоит на это указать и все же дать правильный ответ (если он возможен). Хотя и сам вопрос имхо чрезвычайно мутен.

Comment: @Kromster, да нет, не мутный. Ситуация: `смотрю книгу, вижу фигу`. Я же дал ссылку на статью, которую он понял не верно и написал о чем она на самом деле. Даже слова выделил жирненьким шрифтом, что бы показать, что они разные.